# PHPExcel will download empty file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to download my excel file with PHPExcel and it will download a file..but it's empty..! Basically I tried to modify the 01simple.php example (which works fine when the file is saved into the server) to download the file. But it is an empty file. I read few examples and topics around but still I'm a bit confused. this is my code. thank you

```
<?php

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
/*
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');*/

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("at")
                         ->setLastModifiedBy("At")
                         ->setTitle("title")
                         ->setSubject("Libro ")
                         ->setDescription("Libro")
                         ->setKeywords("excel openxml php")
                         ->setCategory("At");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
        ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Libro Soci aa. 2015');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Libro Soci 2015.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

solved by adding ob_end_clean at the end of the sheet just output

Comment: Well it probably doesn't help that you're setting the headers for a BIFF-format .xls file, but actually sending an OfficeOpenXML-format .xlsx file

Comment: Why not take a look at `01simple-download-xlsx.php` and `01simple-download-xls.php` to check that they work correctly for you.... because there may be additional headers required dependent on browser/version/platform/ssl and those examples should use all appropriate headers

Comment: ok..they seems to work but I guess the charset is wrong as I see weird characters in all the cells. I set utf-8 charset in my php page but if I try to open the document as utf 8 I will see ? instead of letters. If I open the document with Latin 3 charset I will see proper letters..but they are not the Hello World that should be..there are thousands of random letters..note that I'm using openOffice (calc) instead of excel

Comment: Charset is irrelevant, it's a heading for the benefit of the browser if it chooses to render data, and in no way linked to the file itself.

Comment: What you are seeing is the raw stream of binary data that makes up the OfficeOpenXML-format Excel file.... and if you're seeing that, it almost certainly means that your file is corrupted in some way, perhaps because your code has injected something additional into the php output stream.... `echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";` and all those other echoes will do that.... if sending to php://output, there must be absolutely no additional echoes/print statements in your code

Comment: mmm I just copied and pasted the code from the examples..added nothing..in the simple download examples there are not any echo..

Comment: Au contraire, you made changes and additions.... the download examples have absolutely no echo statements in them unless it's the die() when not running in the Web SAPI.... and none of the CLI examples write to php://output

Comment: The code you've posted above has a series of echo statements as well as sending to php://output

Comment: I updated the code above, now I'm using that one that is the example simple download..nothing is printed with echo and the die is commented out

Comment: Well make sure that you've set the correct include for PHPExcel

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. Look for leading/trailing whitespace characters (new lines, spaces, tabs, etc). Look for a BOM header (there shouldn't be one. Look for any obvious plaintext error messages.

Comment: Try saving the file to server disk rather than to php://output, then see if it will open correctly

Comment: the include is correct (otherwise I would get an error). saving the files onto the server is fine and both (xls and xlsx) files work properly when I open them (even with accents and other special characters). this is with the 01simple example. if I open the downloaded files with notepad++ I see just uppercase words..I have no idea how to read that nor look for errors

Comment: If you're sending an Open Office Calc file, then the extension should be `.ods` and the mime/content type should be `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet`; headers as per `01simple-download-ods.php`

Comment: As a temporary workround, do an ob_end_clean() immediately before the save(); this should flush anything that might otherwise be sent to the browser as part of the output stream

Comment: ok now it works! I saw I needed just the ob_end_clean(). now works both with ods and xls..thank you! :)

Comment: Note that using ob_end_clean() is simply a workround.... it means that something in your script is still injecting output into the php://output stream, and the real solution is to find and fix that